# BabylonJS Intellisense for Sublime Text?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, sublimetext3, babylonjs

I see that BabylonJS has nice intellisense for Visual Studio with this line of code:

```
    /// <reference path="/scripts/babylon.js" />
```

And I also see this attempt in Sublime Text.
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/16370-babylonjs-and-autocompletion-in-sublime-text/

Is there an intellisense ability for BabylonJS in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: Sublime Text autocompletion seemed too invasive, and I am not switching to Microsoft Visual Studio because of the overhead. Instead, I noticed that the intellisense or autocompletion is included in the BabylonJS Playground. +1

So when you need to go look up a member or a parameter -> that is the best way.
http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#